# How to prevent formulas changing when deleting rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a COUNTIFS formula that looks at a defined range. When I delete data from the sheet, that the formula is referencing, the range then changes.

An example of the formula I am using is =COUNTIFS(Active!$Q$2:$Q$1000,"Handle Ticket").

When I delete the rows I dont need on the Active sheet the formula then amends the $Q$1000 part of the formula to $Q$520

I have played around with INDIRECT, however i would ideally like to use a non volitile function.

I am hoping that there is a way to have my COUNTIFS formula look at all the data, in the Active sheet, even after I have deleted some rows.

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you select `Q:Q` instead of `$Q$2:$Q$1000`?

Comment: It works, however I am attempting to keep this file as small as possible, therefore by defining an end row allows this, rather than the formula refering to a whole column.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX with hard-coded row references.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(Active!$Q:$Q, 2):INDEX(Active!$Q:$Q, 1000),"Handle Ticket").
```

Comment: So simple, but works perfectly. Thank you for your help.